# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ Divergent? Did I do this right?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} <\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}} \le \frac{1}{n},  \forall n\ge1$$
Then by The Comparison Test with $b_n$, where $b_n$ is a divergent p-series  = $\frac{1}{n}$ and $a_n \le b_n$,

Then
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ is Divergent.

Comment: Repeat your reasoning with $a_n=0$, for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Does it raise any flags?

Comment: It doesn't work: for the divergence test, it's the smallest one which has to diverge. You can use *equivalence*, as this is a series with positive terms.

Comment: @Bernard Oh right on, if $b_n$ is used for comparison, and $b_n$ is divergent, then $a_n$ has to be $\ge$ $b_n$ right?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, you can't conclude. That's the superiority of equivalence: equivalent sequences have the same behaviour, because it ensures none of the sequences is too far away from the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This conclusion is not quite correct.  Note that $n^2+1>n^2 \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}<\frac1n$ is correct.  But $\frac{1}{n^2}\le \frac1n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Instead, we can assert that for $n\ge 1$, $n^2+1\le 2n^2$.  Therefore, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,n}$.  And since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ diverges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$.

Comment: Okay makes sense. I misused the theorem. Instead, I could use your method or the Limit Comparison test, i.e., $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$

Comment: @Romaion, the limit comparison test is not applicable here :); the limit is $1$. As the answerer shows, once we note that we can get a more informative lower bound for $1/\sqrt{n^{2}+1}$ pointwisely, we know by comparison test that the series under consideration diverges.

Comment: @WalkingBlues, Point taken :) However, the limit being = 1 explicitly implies that the series either converges or diverges based on the series we're comparing it too.

Comment: @walkingblues Why is thr LCT not useful here?  If the limit exists and is finite, then either both series duverge or both converge.  Since we know that the harmonic series diverges, we're done.

Comment: My mistake; was not paying enough attention to what I wrote to "correct" :) Sorry, @Dr.MV and Romaion